# Python function not producing desired result

Tags: python, python-3.x, kaggle

I am working with the Kaggle Titanic dataset and am playing around with some data cleaning. When I run the below, the dataframe (df) is unchanged. When I run the code outside of the function, it works as intended (drops columns, imputes missing data). Any ideas?

```
def clean_data(data):
    data = data.drop(['Name','Cabin','PassengerId','Ticket'],axis=1)
    data['Embarked']=data['Embarked'].fillna(data['Embarked'].mode()[0]) 
    data['Fare']=data['Fare'].fillna(data['Fare'].mode()[0]) 
    data

clean_data(df)
```

Comment: Do all of them with `inplace=True`, not by assignment. (e.g. `data.drop([cols], 1, inplace=True)`)

Comment: use `return data` in last line of function. And `df = clean_data(df)`

Comment: Assignment is fine if you return and replace the original. But yeah, inplace is generally less wasteful

Answer (score 0):

You must write:

```
df = clean_data(df)
```